# Query and filter odata 3 levels in

Tags: api, odata

I am trying to query an object that has the following structure:

```
Courses{
NameId: <String>
  Classes{
    Sections{
    Type: <String>
      Meetings{
        MeetingId:
        Instructor:
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to make an API call that would query courses for a particular iD, then expand all the Sections, query those by their type, and expand the meetings of the queried Sections.

The call I am currently making is:

```
/Courses?%24expand=Classes($filter=NameId%20eq%202041be50df-312c-440f-8bae-edd993c675b2;$expand=Sections($expand=Meetings))
```

I did not add the second $filter because the first one is already failing.

Appreciate your help!